# rank of categories

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I'm trying to find a method which could rank categorical variable.

I have a categorical (also ordinal) independent variable in a statistic model. And I would like to have an order of those categories according to the level of importance (or contribution to dependent variable). In such way that I could know which category is more/less important than another.

Can someone give me any suggestion?

Comment: It would seem that "contribution to dependent variable" is another term for *estimated coefficient.* Why wouldn't its absolute value be the basis for determining "importance," then?

Comment: Thanks. I can get estimated coefficient for the categorical variable in a regression model. But it cannot distinguish the importance of each category. For example, in a study, I would like to analyze whether big parks or small parks or maybe medium parks is more efficient to promote people's walking behavior. So I classify the parks into several categories, and I want to know which category is the most effective one, or if possible, I can rank the categories according to its effectiveness. Hope this could clarify my question.

Comment: I'm afraid it makes it murky, because you seem to be distinguishing "effective" and "efficient" from the size of the regression coefficient.  So what exactly do you mean by these terms?  How would they be measured and reflected in your data?

Comment: Suppose I have a categorical independent variable, in which I have 4 categories namely 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'. I know if I run a regression, I could get the regression coefficient of the categorical variable. But the regression coefficient is not I wanted. What I really like to know is in the 4 categories, which category generates more outcome when controlling all the other variables.

Comment: For examples, if we take human heights as the outcome variable, and his/her country as a categorical variable. We could find one Northern European country to have taller people than any other countries when we control for ages, genders and etc..